# Getting hidden form field with json list using AngularJs

Tags: php, angularjs

I have this situation:

Part of my PHP file:

```
<form action="fechar_pedido.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-controller="carrinhoQtdeController">

    <?php 
        $json_data = array();

        foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $key => $value)
        {
            $json_array = array();
            $prod_info = array_values($value); 
            $json_array += array($prod_info[0] . '-' . $prod_info[1]=>array("id" => $prod_info[0], "tamanho" => $prod_info[1], "qtde" => $prod_info[2], "classificacao" => intval($prod_info[3]), "id_depto" =>  intval($prod_info[4]),"id_categ" => intval($prod_info[5]),"id_subcateg" => intval($prod_info[6])));

            array_push($json_data, $json_array);
        }

        $json_data = json_encode($json_data);
                ?>                      

<input type="hidden" ng-model="jsoncart" value="<?php echo $json_data; ?>" />
```

Above, I have a foreach that fills an array with my current cart products, and transforms this array in a json format list.

After that, I set a hidden form field with this json list. My idea is get this value in my angular function, described below.

Here is the result of my hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="jsoncart" value="[{"1-XGG":{"id":1,"tamanho":"XGG","qtde":4,"classificacao":7,"id_depto":1,"id_categ":1,"id_subcateg":4}},{"2-M":{"id":2,"tamanho":"M","qtde":1,"classificacao":4,"id_depto":1,"id_categ":1,"id_subcateg":4}}]" />
```

Here is part of my angular file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('carrinhoQtdeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.bill = { total: 0, subtotal: 0 };
    $scope.items = "";
    $scope.param = "?jsoncart=" + $scope.jsoncart; <----- Here I try to get hidden field value !!!!
    $http.get("./fetch_carrinho.php" + $scope.param)
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.items = response;
        })
        .error(function(error) {
            alert(error);
            $scope.carrinho = "error in fetching data";
    });

    var calculateTotals = function() {
        var total = 0;

        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.items.length; i < len; i++) {
            total = total + 
                $scope.items[i].price * 
                $scope.items[i].quantity;
        }

        $scope.bill.total = total;
        $scope.bill.subtotal = total - $scope.bill.discount;
    };
 });
```

In the line indicated, I try to join the url with the jsoncart model, but I can´t get its value. In the hidden field, I have already used "value", "ng-value", "ng-bind", but I can´t get the value in any case.

So, my question is how to get the hidden field value ?

Thanks,
Marcelo.

Comment: I think, your design approach is not good. anyway, I assume that some quotes problem..change that the value attribute enclose with single quotes and try!

Comment: I am getting "undefined in $scope.jsoncart. The '' did not make any change.
By the way, my approch here is not completed... Its part of a solution, but I need to resolve this one to go forward...

Comment: wrong, you need study more about AngularJS, for begginer like you I recomment MongoDB. its easier.

Comment: DeFirmo, if u do not have anything constructive to say, be quiet. It is not your business if I am a beginner or not... I am here looking for help, and not looking for any other technology.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Angular does its magic after your page is loaded. Since you've populated your input with a value prior to Angular executing, it overwrote the value with the content of your ng-model variable, jsoncart.

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div><input name="first" ng-model="first" value="abc"></div> <-- this is blank after Angular runs
    <div><input name="second" value="def"></div>
    <p>first: {{first}}</p>
  </body>
```

See the full plunkr: plnkr.co/edit/87NPheulFXofU5LdE5hK?p=preview

To solve this problem, you'd have to populate your jsoncart instead of your input.

Update 1:
Updated plnkr to show how you can get string from static HTML value. [plnkr.co/edit/87NPheulFXofU5LdE5hK?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/87NPheulFXofU5LdE5hK?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I got what u have said. But, I need to send my json cart to a service, using this:
$scope.param = "?jsoncart=" + $scope.jsoncart;
$http.get($url + $scope.param)
This http.get will happen when the user access the cart page, to validate each line. So, how can I have this json cart built before sending it to the service ?

Comment: AngularJS is not meant to be used as a page scripting language like jQuery. Having said that, it doesn't prevent you from using these hacks to make things work. Here's the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/87NPheulFXofU5LdE5hK?p=preview

Comment: Does this answer your question or do you need more clarification?